# VS2017 Breakpoint within a DLL

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2017

I have a program that has one DLL calling functions in another DLL. Works fine. However, I would like to set a breakpoint at the address of a function in the nested DLL. dumpbin shows me the relative offset in the DLL, but the Modules window in VS2017 doesn't show the DLL at all. I don't have pdb's for either DLL. How can I get the starting address of the loaded DLL ?

Thanks !

Comment: If by dll u mean `class` and if so, then if u created the class,u can always set a breakpoint

Comment: Breakpoint to what if you don't have the source?

Comment: To the entry point of the DLL function. I just want to know when and if that function is being called.

Comment: You have to enable unmanaged debugging to see anything at all.  Project > Properties > Debug tab.

Answer (score 0):

`Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Uncheck "Just my Code"` 
Also give a try : https://hmemcpy.com/2014/07/how-to-debug-anything-with-visual-studio-and-jetbrains-dotpeek-v1-2/